# Tag Merge Requests

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We've got:

[printing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/printing)-[printers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/printers)-[printerdriver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/printerdriver)

[driver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/driver)-[drivers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the questions with [printerdriver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/printerdriver) were also tagged with another relevant printing tag, so I merged it into [drivers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/drivers) as well.